# Highlight the active subitem inside item-active in carousel slider php

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am trying to achieve as shown below in the image.
I want to create a image carousel slider in which I have 4 items having 4 slides each.
This images act like a radio button selection I am getting the list from the database, so I want to highlight which radio button is selected by highlighting the slide which comes as selected.
So whenever the carousel loads it should highlight the slide which is selected as radio input

[Simple Carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK2Ho.png)

Here is the link of it : https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-carousel

Here is my Code :

```
<div class="carousel-inner">

<?php
  $result = '';
  foreach ($template_data as $key => $value) {

    if ($key == 0) {
      $result .= '<div class="item active">';
    }
    elseif ($key !=0 && ($key % 4 == 0)) { 
      //to avoid first empty "active"
      $result .= "</div>";
      $result .= '<div class="item">';
    }

    $result .= '<div class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="#" title="#"></a></div>';
  }

  $result .= '</div>';
  echo $result;
?> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your basic premise looks good to me, though an [example on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or the like highlighting the problem would be much better.  For future questions, consider that.

Meanwhile, I might consider reorganizing your code such that there is never ambiguity of when you write the opening and closing element tags.  If you open a tag, close it.  Always:

```
<?php
    $result = '';
    foreach ($template_data as $key => $value) {

        $cssClass = 'item';
        if ( /* Your test to determine 'active'; you currently have $key == 0 */ ) {
            $cssClass .= ' active';
        }

        $result .= "<div class='$cssClass'><div class='col-md-3'><a href='#'><img src='http://placehold.it/250x250' alt='#' title='#'></a></div></div>";
    }

    echo $result;
?>
```

The only if-check necessary should be to determine if the item is active.  If so, modify it accordingly.  Otherwise, the loop is *the same for every item*.  Much easier to write, read, and reason about later.